# c #define identifier

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Is it possible in C to influence how the define identifier is composed? For example, there is the following (external lib) define that cannot be changed:

```
#define GPIO_13_GPIO13                  0x00061A00U
```

I then create my own one:

```
#define MY_GPIO_NO (13)
```

Now, I would like to create a macro name that points to the `GPIO_13_GPIO13`, but only because `MY_GPIO_NO` is set to 13. Something like:

```
// should become GPIO_13_GPIO13 because MY_GPIO_NO = 13
#define CUSTOM_GPIO_DEF (GPIO_ ## MY_GPIO_NO  _GPIO ## MY_GPIO_NO)
```

The above should be threated as pseudo-code, just to emphasize on what is it that I am trying to do. The rationale behind this is to have just 1 define definition that can control different defines with a pattern.

Comment: How is it variadic? I do not anything related to variadic here. The title is misleading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, it can be done with some smoke and mirrors:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define GPIO_13_GPIO13                  0x00061A00U
#define MY_GPIO_NO 13    // Have to remove parenthesis since this will be part of a name
#define combine(s1,s2,s3,s4) s1 ## s2 ## s3 ## s4
#define expandCombine(s1,s2,s3,s4) combine(s1,s2,s3,s4)
#define CUSTOM_GPIO_DEF (expandCombine(GPIO_,MY_GPIO_NO,_GPIO,MY_GPIO_NO)) 

int main()
{
    printf("%08x", CUSTOM_GPIO_DEF);
}
```

Comment: With the question being, "...but *should*  you?", and the answer "probably not". ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is probably more obfuscating than just creating 2 separate `#define` macros instead...

Comment: @DevSolar Haha, you are probably right. That being said, I am happy you say "probably". I am actually using a construct similar to this in a case (unfortunately too long to describe here) where I believe it was the best solution all things considered. Over the years I have become careful about using the word "never". There is often some weird case which is difficult to image unless having seen it.

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło You are welcome. - And, yes, I would not recommend using such tricks unless there is a very good reason for it.